# Octave project structuring

Tags: architecture, octave

First I would like to shortly describe what I do for living and what I'm now trying to achieve in a side project:

I'm an embedded SW engineer, so I'm usually writing some real-time stuff in C. I think I know the language quite well and I'm also doing my best to keep the code modular, have high granularity, avoiding complicated interfaces, structuring it in some logical way... Usually I'm a messy guy, but when it comes to software projects, I understand the need of having stuff organized, structured, logical and clean.

Now, for my side project, I decided to use Octave to analyze bigger sets of data. Since I can already see that there's going to be quite some code needed, I would like to know how to get structured project that's not just hundreds of function files (each containing a single function) in a single folder, together with few scripts... If my code will grow a bit, I'll go crazy soon.

Are there any general recommendations how to structure a bigger project in Octave in a way it's sustainable and reusable? Or is it inevitable that I will soon or later find myself in a mess of hundreds of files, all in a single folder together with scripts, saved workspaces etc.?

Comment: this doesn't depend on Octave... I typically have a directories data/raw/experiment123, scripts/analysis, scripts/visualisation scripts/report_generation and so on. Then a buch of Makefiles so you can do a "make clean" and a "make" filters my raw data, runs the analysis, creates figures and reports (latex). But hey, it's all up to you

Comment: Ok, I will re-specify the question a bit: Is there a way how to have multi-folder structure of the project (for example the one you mentioned), having the Octave workspace folder set to the top folder of the structure and having access from there to all the defined functions, raw data files etc. in the folders below? Without having to change the workspace folder all the time?

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: I tried. I had structure of folders like this:
-level1
--level2_folder1
--level2_folder2
...
having the script on level1 and moving the function files into folders on level2. When running the script from level1, Octave was complaining that the function I was trying to call from the script isn't defined. From that I concluded it's not that easy to achieve and that was the reason I was asking - I don't know about any options how to tell Octave where it has to look for functions/files etc. when it doesn't find it in the current folder or in built-in functions.